# export gridview to excel sheet

Tags: c#, asp.net

I had soluation to export gridview rows to excel sheet .I did that well but when I opened the excel sheet the language which in gridview apeared whit unkown language as this(Ø§Ù„Ø¬ÙŠØ²Ø©) this is arabic language .So please any one help me

Comment: and your 100 million dollar question is ?

Comment: as I understand, his gridview data language is not arabic, but exported data's language is arabic I think.

Comment: gridview had both data english and arabic

Comment: what is your regional setting? and what happens when arabic data exported to excel?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have a look at [this](http://www.dotnetspider.com/resources/2753-Export-data-from-excel-file-with-special-character.aspx) example, maybe it solves your encoding issue.

```
Response.ContentEncoding = Encoding.Unicode;
Response.BinaryWrite(Encoding.Unicode.GetPreamble());
```

Answer (score 1):

If your question is like my comment, and if you have different regional setting (not enUS) this should be culture info problem. I can suggest you to use a trick like this

```
CultureInfo oldCulture = Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture;
        Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture = new CultureInfo("en-US");

//Fill your excel sheet in this part, and return old culture

Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture = oldCulture;
```